# Using a thread inside a CDI Singleton bean

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

In `JEE6` is it ok to use a Thread inside a `CDI` `@Singleton` bean that `@Produces` a connection to an external third-party service.

I have a JEE6 war that does exactly this:

```
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;


@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyBean {

    @Produces
    public SomeService getSomeService() {

        /** Retry a number of times to connect to some service **/
        SomeService someService = retry("127.0.0.1");

        return someService;
    }
}
```

The retry method will try a number of times to connect to the service. It uses a `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` to re-attempt the connection every x seconds.

I believe in `JEE7` they've added a Managed Executor for this kind of thing. But is it ok to use a normal Executor in `JEE6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java EE 6 it is not acceptable to start a thread inside an EJB.  In Java EE 7 they have made a little more relaxed.

Comment: So in the JEE6 world what would be the best approach to solve this problem?

My main problem is I'm creating a bean with @Produces and this may be a long running operation?

Comment: It would need to be synchronous.  Even in EE7, a `@Produces` (CDI) method should be synchronous.

Comment: John is correct. I'll expand a bit on why doing threads in Java EE 6 and lower isn't acceptable. Whenever you start your own thread the server no longer manages anything in this thread. You get no transactions, on container services, no injection, etc. Also because the server doesn't manage it, there is no guarantee everything will be cleaned up when the server shuts down which can lead to zombie processes and memory leaks at least, security concerns at worst. It simply isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

For running time-consuming operations in JEE6 you can use @Asynchronous annotation in EJB. It will start you method asynchronously in a separate container-managed thread, all legal. Here's a great example: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/conveniently_transactionally_and_legally_starting